# (JAVA) Parameter and return types error

Tags: java, parameters, return-type

can someone tell me whats wrong with my code? It gives me an error of "**truefalse** cannot be resolved into a variable" The question is asking me to return a value of true, if the int number is even, and false, if it is an odd number.

```
public class number{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        boolean truefalse = isEven(245);
        System.out.print(truefalse);
    }
    public static boolean isEven(int number) {

        if(number%2 == 0){
            boolean truefalse = true;
        }
        else{
            boolean truefalse = false;
        }
        return truefalse;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `truefalse` outside the if-else blocks , or the return statement won't know what it is .

Comment: please have a look at 'scope' term of variables

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the problem you have is declaring `truefalse` inside the `if-else` blocks, so the `return` statements doesn't know what it is (scope issues). Here are some fixes:

### Solution 1

You can simplify your `isEven()` class to this:

```
public static boolean isEven(int number) {

    if(number%2 == 0){
        return  true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

To keep the boolean, do this

```
public static boolean isEven(int number) {
    boolean truefalse;
    if(number%2 == 0){
        truefalse =  true;
    }
    else{
        truefalse = false;
    }
    return truefalse;
}
```

### Solution 3

To keep the boolean, but minimize code woth boolean logic, do this:

```
public static boolean isEven(int number) {
    boolean truefalse = false;
    if(number%2 == 0){
        truefalse =  true;
    }
    return truefalse;
}
```

### Solution 4

The most you can simplify you function is like this:

```
public static boolean isEven(int number) {

    return number % 2 == 0;
}
```

This would also have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `boolean truefalse;` outside if-else block. It has truefalse variable inside if-else block, which is has no scope outside if-else. So returned variable can not be resolved.

```
public static boolean isEven(int number) {

boolean truefalse;

    if(number%2 == 0){
        truefalse = true;
    }
    else{
        truefalse = false;
    }
    return truefalse;
}
```

Simple `isEven` could be:

```
public static boolean isEven(int number) {    
    return (number%2 == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it outside If else block

```
boolean truefalse = isEven(245);
        System.out.print(truefalse);
    }
    public static boolean isEven(int number) {
     boolean truefalse =false;
        if(number%2 == 0){
            truefalse = true;
        }

        return truefalse;
    }
```

Comment: the else block in your code is uneccessary, it seems redundant. without it the logic wouldn't change

Comment: Thx Arnav I forget to focus on that

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following.

```
public class number{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        boolean truefalse = isEven(245);
        System.out.print(truefalse);
    }
    public static boolean isEven(int number) {
        boolean truefalse = false;
        if(number%2 == 0){
            truefalse = true;
        }

        return truefalse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more readable will be

```
public static boolean isEven(int number){
  return number%2 == 0? true: false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should read on [java variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

What is happening in your is `isEven` method is you are declaring `truefalse`  variable inside `if` `{}` and `else` `{}`, but outside those brackets, where `return` is, this variable does not exist.

So, as so many answers mention you should declare the variable in correct scope e.g.

```
 public static boolean isEven(int number) {
        boolean truefalse;
        if(number%2 == 0){
            truefalse = true;
        }
        else{
            truefalse = false;
        }
        return truefalse;
    }
```